# Today's date: Moment construction falls back to js Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want today's date like: `2017/06/23`

I am doing this:

```
moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD'))
```

It gives me error:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release.

Tried many solutions from SO and also Github issue, still nothing is working out. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Are you using an old version of `moment`? I've just used the [latest](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js) on CDNJS and it works fine, no warning.

Comment: version : 2.8.4

Comment: Try 2.18.1: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js

Comment: Then try 2.18.1

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `new Date()` without parameters to moment object.

```js
console.log(moment(new Date()).format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you see, I have used the 2.8.4 version only and it works. If it still doesn't work for you try updating the version to the latest one that is `2.18.1`